# Facebook debug returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-403

I am trying to run my URL through [Facebook's Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see if I have setup the correct meta tags, and also, to see that stuff works in general.

When I put my URL in, I get a `403 Forbidden` in return.

The URL is to a subdomain, and the domain itself also returns `403 Forbidden`.

Reading another post [Facebook links to my site resolve as 403 forbidden](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2925620/facebook-links-to-my-site-resolve-as-403-forbidden), I think that my host might have setup a block or something, however, I can't seem to recreate the block from my computer.

I have been trying to spoof the referrer and the user agent, but without luck. Before calling my host, what could I have missed?

If it's of relevance the URL in question is: http://distorpia.dadiugames.dk/

Comment: Try your host first to rule out that possibility.

Comment: I just wanted something to tell them when I called them, so they didn't just give me an empty answer.

Comment: I know, but you could spend hours trying to debug the problem when it could be a setting or fault on their part. 5 minutes on the phone to check with them could save you wasting hours of heartache!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command I use to test this issue is `curl -i -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Range: bytes=0-40960' -H 'Connection: close' -A 'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)' http://whatever.com` - this includes some of the headers sent by the Facebook crawler that some hosts have problems with

Looks like your hosting setup can't handle one/some of those headers properly - I replicated the 403 error:

For your URL, this returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Tue, 13 Dec 2011 20:54:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.6 mod_auth_kerb/5.3 PHP/5.2.17 mod_fcgid/2.3.6
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Parallels H-Sphere</title>

{{REMOVED THIS PART}}

    <h2>Error 403: Forbidden</h2>

<p>You don't have permissions to access this page.
This usually means one of the following:</p>
<ul>
<li>this file and directory permissions make them unavailable from the Internet.</li>
<li>.htaccess contains instructions that prevent public access to this file or directory.</li>
</ul>
<p>Please check file and directory permissions and .htaccess configuration if you are able to do this.
Otherwise, request your webmaster to grant you access.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine with all the above headers, but the "Range" one.  Are you sure Facebook sends "Range: bytes=0-40960" and not "Content-Range: bytes=0-40960"? This works. I'll be calling my host in the morning for an explanation. How I wish I had access to the logs :)

Comment: I'm nearly sure it's 'Range' based on previous testing, i'll see if i can get a definite answer from the crawler code

Comment: Yep, definitely 'Range', 'bytes=0-40960' - checked the code of the crawler itself

Answer (score 0):

Facebook & Facebook Debugger sends:

```
curl -i -H 'Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Range: bytes=0-524287' -H 'User-Agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)' https://your.website/something
```

The problem may be in the owasp-modsecurity-crs rule `#958291`, which gives false-positive result: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/issues/173

Check it by sending request with header `Range: bytes=524287` (in place of `Range: bytes=0-524287`):

```
curl -i -H 'Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Range: bytes=524287' -H 'User-Agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)' https://your.website/something
```

#### Solution

- remove this rule https://github.com/theasci/owasp-modsecurity-crs/commit/c8230c462c0b0df243146945327bf3fb711bd016

  ```
  #SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Range "@beginsWith bytes=0-" "phase:2,rev:'2',ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',maturity:'6',accuracy:'8',t:none,block,msg:'Range: field exists and begins with 0.',logdata:'%{matched_var}',severity:'4',id:'958291',tag:'OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_HREQ',setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.warning_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_HREQ-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}"
  ```
- or just update OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set (CRS) https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset