# Facebook won't display images, when website link is inserted

Tags: facebook, debugging, joomla

So,
I have this joomla-based website [MAIS +](http://www.facebook.com/canalmaismz), and every time I share an article on Facebook, either from it (site) or directly on Facebook, an image is not inserted.

I have tried the Facebook debug tool and what I got was [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.mais.co.mz) 
![Facebook Debug Tool][3]

Problem is, what to do with this information?

I don't get it!! :(

Comment: Can you please share some code?  What version of Joomla are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Well in the Facebook debugger, it's returning a 403 error which if you read here;

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

> A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response
>   to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that
>   the server refuses to allow the requested action. In other words, the
>   server can be reached, but the server declined to allow the requested
>   access.

This may mean that your server could be blocking the Facebook server's from accessing your URL. Check your firewall with your hosting provider to see if any blocking is going on.

If you look at what Facebook see's of your URL;

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mais.co.mz%2F

It states;

> Document returned no data

Here's a solution - [Facebook debug returns 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494059/facebook-debug-returns-403-forbidden)

Comment: Quick question... all site images are hosted by CDN. May this be interfering?

Comment: I don't think it's the CDN as Facebook can't access your site at all, plus I can see some of your images are hosted on the same server.

Comment: Check out this solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494059/facebook-debug-returns-403-forbidden

Comment: That is because I turned of the **CDN** plugin, temporarily! :(