# Facebook can't scrape my site correctly - PHP Site

Tags: facebook, scraper

I am running this website www.miswag.net which is highly dependent on Facbeook. When I share my site on Facebook, I get a "403 Forbidden", here's Facebook's debugger output when I try to scrape my site: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.miswag.net

Please help figure this out.. Thanks

Comment: Make sure Facebook scraper agent is white listed

Comment: I found this in my Apache's access log: GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php). Why does it say 404? It seems Facebook is trying to access index.html which I used to keep while the site was under development and now it's removed. @AdamAzad.. Thanks

Comment: You can check if the agent has `facebookexternalhit/1.1` and return a custom header (200 OK) `if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], array(
  'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)',
  'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)'
))) {
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
else {
  echo "You're not Facebook agent '__'";
}`
source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8626828

Comment: solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64169793/1679903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook's scraper doesn't need to read the full page, so they only request part of it by sending a Range header. However, your server seems to be responding incorrectly to that request and returning a 403 error code. You need to check your server and make sure it handles the range header correctly.

To see this in action, try this CURL command:

```
curl -H "Range: bytes=0-524287" http://www.miswag.net
```

This is the response I got:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /
on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: The problem is I am on a shared hosting! I was looking into my WHM and seems like I cannot go that far. I think I need consider finding a vps or something

Answer (score 0):

Compounding on @Waleed'sanswer, if you want to test right away, use [Online CURL](http://onlinecurl.com)

1. fill in `www.wiswag.net`
2. ADD OPTION options, choosing `--header (-H)`
3. next to it `"Range: bytes=0-524287"`
4. `CURL` button